# OEM SSD w/ Thinkpad T430 - with only 1 SMART attribute, how should I tell wear?

Tags: ssd, thinkpad, smart

I recently purchased a Thinkpad T430 with a 128GB SSD. I'd like to get an idea of how well the SSD is holding up, so I install CrystalDiskInfo and look at the list of SMART attributes.

Unfortunately, there is only one attribute listed - "0C", "Power Cycle Count." The Current value is 100, the Worst 100, and the Raw 000000000050.

The ID number (or whatever it is called) is listed as "C400-MTFDDAK128MAM", which would seem to indicate that it is [this](http://www.cdwg.com/shop/products/Micron-RealSSD-C400-SED-solid-state-drive-128-GB-SATA-600/2829607.aspx). I thought I might try to update the firmware to see if that might help more SMART attributes reveal themselves, but for some reason, I'm unable to download the latest firmware in Chrome, Internet Explorer or Firefox.

Is there any way to tell the health of this SSD, either without additional SMART attributes or by making additional ones available?

Comment: What version of CrystalDiskInfo did you use? Where exactly are you trying to download the firmware from?

Comment: @techie007 using CrystalDiskInfo 5.1.1, and downloaded the firmware from Micron's website after registering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Micron C400 SSDs cause a lot of problems for us in the T430s. Lenovo recently published a [firmware update](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?DocID=HT076505) that supposedly will fix them. I did not look at the SMART attributes of the new version, but you may have more success with upgrading to this one.